# How to reference .net framework 4.8 nuget package from .net standard 2.0 class library?

Tags: .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I'm trying to use .net framework 4.8 nuget package (which was written by our team) in my .net standard 2.0 class library.
But when I build the solution I see such kind of warning:

Warning NU1701
Package ... was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

At the same time [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0) it is claimed that .net standard and .net framework 4.8 are compatible.

Why do I see this warning? What am I doing wrong?
Is there way to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

They're compatible in the sense that you can reference `netstandard` projects from `net48` projects, but not the other way round.

The only thing you can reference from a `netstandard` project is another `netstandard` project